# How do I get the inverse of a homogeneous transformation matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, inverse, geometric-transform, rotation

I want to get the inverse of this homogeneous transformation matrix:

```
iab = {
 {1, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, -1, 0},
 {0, 1, 0, 3},
 {0, 0, 0, 1}
      }
```

using the inverse function, but the problem is that I cannot directly use this function. Somehow I have to convert first the matrix to a transformation function.

```
iba = InverseFunction[iab] // MatrixForm
```

Using that I don't get any result. I can use `TranslationTransform` and `RotationTransform` to compute the inverse, but the problem with that approach is that I can only create a rotation matrix or a translation matrix, but not both in one transformation like in the above matrix I posted.

Comment: I'm confused: your matrix is not invertible. If it *was*, you could just use `Inverse`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why my matrix is not invertible? I tried using Inverse and I got the following result: Inverse::sing: Matrix {{1,0,0,0},{0,0,-1,0},{0,1,0,3},{0,0,0,0}} is singular. >>

Comment: You can write a function which does the inversion. However, you cannot use the `Inverse[]` as inverse of transformation matrix is different than inverse of a general matrix. By inverse of transformation matrix we mean the matrix which takes back a rigid body to original orientation and position.

Comment: By the way the `(4,4)` element in your transformation matrix should be $1$ or some scaling factor, not $0$.

Comment: Your matrix is singular because the last row is all zeros. Or to put it another way: `Det[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}]` returns zero.

Comment: @Saurav. Oh I see: this matrix actually represents a transformation which includes both a rotation and a translation, and the usual rules don't apply because it's not a direct linear representation of what's going on with the coordinates (I just looked it up, because I wasn't familiar with this). But yes: it looks like the last row should not be all zeros.

Comment: Yes, @Saurav you are right. It is one.

Comment: So, there is no a function that I can use to compute the inverse of the homogeneous transformation matrix?

Comment: Built-in? Not that I know of, but I'm writing an answer right now, based on what I understand the inverse to be. Hold on a sec.

Answer (score 15):

If you have a homogenous transformation matrix of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathrm{R_{3 \times 3}}       & \mathrm{d}_{3 \times 1} \\
    0_{1\times 3} & 1_{1\times 1}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the inverse is given by
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathrm{R}^{-1}       & -\mathrm{R}^{-1}\mathrm{d} \\
    0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, if your homogeneous matrix is (I have added the 1 in the lower corner that I think should be there)

```
iab = {{1, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, -1, 0},
       {0, 1, 0, 3},
       {0, 0, 0, 1}
      };
```

then the inverse can be written as (note that for rotation matrices, the inverse is the transpose)

```
homogeneousTransformationInverse[mat_] /; Dimensions[mat] == {4, 4} :=
  Module[{
     rot = Transpose[mat[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]]],
     vec = mat[[1 ;; 3, -1]],
     inv = mat
    },
   inv[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]] = rot;
   inv[[1 ;; 3, -1]] = -rot.vec;
   inv
  ]
```

[image]

---

I think the above is cleaner than the original version:

```
homogeneousTransformationInverse[mat_] /; Dimensions[mat] == {4, 4} :=
  Module[
   {rot = Transpose[mat[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]]], vec = mat[[1 ;; 3, -1]]},
   ArrayFlatten[{{rot, Map[List, -rot.vec]}, {{{0, 0, 0}}, {{mat[[-1, -1]]}}}}]
  ]
homogeneousTransformationInverse[iab] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: For rotation matrices, the transpose is same as inverse. Should use transpose as they are less expensive than inverse.

Comment: @Saurav. True. Good recommendation. I will fix it.

Comment: I suppose you can mention about the transpose being equal to inverse in the answer. Else someone might end up getting confused as code does not match with the explanation. This should complete the answer.

Comment: Will do when I get the chance. I'm on my way out now. Feel free to make the edit if you wish! I'll approve it.

Comment: I couldn't compute your code. Here is what I get: http://postimg.org/image/bewxouwc3/

Comment: @user702475. Okay, I think I fixed it. Clear the function and try it again (I was missing an underscore).

Comment: How I'd have done it: `homogeneousTransformationInverse[mat_?SquareMatrixQ] /; Length[mat] == 4 := With[{rot = Take[mat, 3, 3]}, Transpose[ArrayFlatten[{{rot, 0}, {{-mat[[;; -2, -1]].rot}, 1}}]]]`. Of course, if the appropriate part of the matrix is not orthogonal, `Inverse[]`/`LinearSolve[]` would be used instead.

Comment: @J.M. I toyed with various things. Your way is cleaner (well, actually, your answer above is actually the best). I always have a hard time getting the correct nesting using `ArrayFlatten`, so once I found the way that works, I went with it.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a nice one-liner:

```
TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}]
// InverseFunction
   TransformationFunction[{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, -3}, {0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}]
```

Note that `TransformationFunction[]` is the head of the results returned by geometric `*Transform` functions, which take a homogeneous transformation matrix as an argument. Since you have the matrix already, you merely need to add the wrapper and then use `InverseFunction[]` to invert the transformation.

---

For future reference: `Composition[]` is a handy way to chain together more than one `TransformationFunction`:

```
Composition[TranslationTransform[{0, 0, 3}], RotationTransform[π/2, {1, 0, 0}]]
```

Alternatively, `AffineTransform[]` allows a direct construction:

```
AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[π/2, {1, 0, 0}], {0, 0, 3}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one's not orthogonal but it is invertible with det = 1, am I missing something? [image: Picture of my simple code]

Dan Bach - [www.dansmath.com](http://www.dansmath.com)